# My website hosted on GoDaddy and it is not visible

Tags: domains, web-hosting, web-development, godaddy

I recently signed up for GoDaddy web hosting, the domain registrar is still BlueHost. Anyways, I uploaded the content of my website to GoDaddy but I can't see anything when trying to view through website's IP Address how ever when I click on Preview Website the website shows up.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: "I can't see anything" - please be specific. If you are on a shared server then it's unlikely you will be able to see _your website_ through the server's IP address.

Comment: @w3dk Yes I am on a shared server. So how will I see my website now?

Comment: I can't see my name servers list anywhere in my Godaddy's cpanel, how will I edit it then in my domain registrar then.

Comment: You would need to access your site by your domain name. If your domain is registered with BlueHost, then you will need to change the NAMESERVERS at BlueHost, not GoDaddy. GoDaddy will tell you what the NAMESERVERS should be set to. This process will take up to 48 hours for the DNS to propagate. Presumably when you setup the account at GoDaddy, you stated what domain you were wanting to use?

Answer (score 1):

As per GoDaddy's [policy](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/i-uploaded-my-files-why-isnt-my-website-displaying-95), please follow these steps:

> - Verify that you uploaded your files to the appropriate directory.
> - Make sure that you named the first page of your website "index.htm" or "default.htm."
> - Ensure that your DNS is pointed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If it was shared hosting, you need to have an assigned domain name to the hosting plan you chose. You can see this when going to My Account and under the *Products* tab.

Try to open that domain name in a new browser tab, if you did not grab another domain or this is not the case, then you need to double check your nameserver settings.

BlueHost's Zone file for your domain needs to include an `A` record pointing to GoDaddy's shared hosting server's IP address, which you can see when logging into cPanel on the left side. See GoDaddy's support page: [What is my website's IP address?](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/what-is-my-websites-ip-address-16112)